# Memory-footprint combobox (search autocomplete)

Tags: combobox, autocomplete, vaadin, vaadin7, memory-footprint

I use vaadin 7.4.6. I use a combobox filled with a list of cities (huge size).

This combobox is loaded from a backend service java.

But, the memory-footprint of this combobox is very consequent.

The users want to use auto-completion during the search of city.

How can I respond to this request ?

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin 7 lacks built-in generic lazy backend support. Thus ComboBox loads all items at once. One of the main benefits of Vaadin 8 and other newer Vaadin versions over Vaadin 7 is added support for callbacks data providers, which makes it clearly better when implementing something you are trying to do.

With Vaadin 7 there exists mixed set of add-on solutions in Vaadin's Directory
to tackle this short coming. Specific for your case is for example the [AutocompleteField](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/autocompletefield-for-vaadin/overview).  There is also more generic solution of [Lazy Query Container](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/lazy-query-container), that can be use with various components accepting container data source (Table, Grid and ComboBox).